# error: <identifier> expected public void setListener (Listener 1) ^ how to resolve this error

Tags: java

[Code snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCJgW.png)

error:  expected
public void setListener (Listener 1)
^

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the method

```java
public void setListener(Listener 1) {
    listener = 1;
}
```

You can't name a variable `1`. Perhaps you meant the letter `l`.

```java
public void setListener(Listener l) {
    listener = l;
}
```

Comment: And naming a variable `1` is *highly discouraged* specifically because it leads to errors like this.

Comment: @Andreas you cannot name a variable `1`. 1 is a number and thus not a valid identifier. However, you can name your variable `l` or `I`, but those are not good identifiers as mentioned: they lack context and meaning and are too easily confused with other characters

Comment: @knittl DOH! Typo! "Naming a variable `l` is *highly discouraged* ..."